# local variable "title" referenced before assignment with JSON crying right now

Tags: python, json, xlsx

ive been trying to get this fixed for 3 days now.
I was making a ikea webcrawler and it kept rising up the error "local variable 'title' referenced before assignment"

```
def get_info_from_url(browser, sub_category, url_main): 
    print(sub_category)
    products_info = []
    browser.get(url_main + "?page=200")
    time.sleep(10)
    cards = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'per-product-link-wrapper')
    for card in cards :
        title = browser.title
        title = title.replace(" - IKEA",'')
        product_name = card.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "withprice-title").text
        product_desc = card.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'withprice-commit').text
        product_price = card.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'withprice-price').text
        print(product_name, product_desc ,product_price)
        product_url = card.get_attribute('href')
        product_code = product_url.split("-")[-1].strip("s/")    
        prod = {

            'sub_category': title,
            'product_info': [{
                'name': product_name,
                'desc': product_desc,
                'price': product_price,
                'product url': product_url,
                'product code': product_code
            }]
        }
        products_info.append(prod)
    with open(f'JSON/{sub_category}/{title}.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(products_info, outfile)
    products_info.append(products_info)
```

there are 67 different links all importing from a excel file and at the 50th or even at random it pops up the error.

```
checking and submitting decoration (50/67)
decoration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ikea crawler\main.py", line 94, in <module>
    product_info = get_info_from_url(driver, sub_category[0], sub_category[1])
  File "d:\ikea crawler\main.py", line 62, in get_info_from_url
    with open(f'JSON/{sub_category}/{title}.json', 'w') as outfile:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'title' referenced before assignment
```

OUTPUT:

```
LINNMON / ADILS table, white/black, 100x60 cm 149
LAGKAPTEN / ADILS desk, white, 120x60 cm 199
LAGKAPTEN / ALEX desk, white, 120x60 cm 699
LAGKAPTEN / MITTBACK desk, light green/birch, 140x60 cm 619
BEKANT desk, white, 120x80 cm 799
MICKE desk, white, 142x50 cm 799
BRUSALI desk, white, 90x52 cm 399
MELLTORP table, white, 75x75 cm 249
LENNART drawer unit, white 79
PÅHL desk, white, 96x58 cm 399
TROTTEN desk, white, 120x70 cm 599
KALLAX / LAGKAPTEN desk combination, white, 77x159x147 cm 748
SANDSBERG table, black, 110x67 cm 249
MICKE desk, white, 105x50 cm 999
IDÅSEN desk, black/beige, 160x80 cm 1,799
BESTÅ BURS desk, high-gloss white, 120x40 cm 1,299
MALM dressing table, white, 120x41 cm 799
ALEX desk, grey-turquoise, 100x48 cm 799
LINNMON / OLOV desk, dark grey/white, 100x60 cm 229
NORDKISA dressing table, bamboo, 76x47 cm 599
UTESPELARE gaming desk, black, 160x80 cm 799
ANFALLARE / ALEX desk, bamboo/white, 140x65 cm 1,019
BATTERN table, pine clear, 105x50 cm 699
PIPLÄRKA desk, 80x63 cm 499
IDÅSEN table, black/dark grey, 140x70x75 cm 1,299
furniture https://www.ikea.cn/cn/en/cat/tables-desks-fu004/
 checking and submitting furniture (20/66)
```

and then the error comes out.

Comment: What if `cards` is empty and `for card in cards` never loops…?!

Comment: the page isnt loading so i might wanna try it removed from the excel file

Comment: yeah its not because the card is empty

Comment: How do you figure…?

Comment: you might be right because the chinese ikea website is absolute slow, sometimes it even doesnt load, i think you are right

Comment: In the future, it will be easier to help if you add a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer, it is not the code's problem its the website itself
the ikea website i am crawling from refuses to load pages from time to time

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).